# IBM Watson SpeechToText empty respond

Tags: c#, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to transcribe an audiofile with Watson AI in c#. The problem i encountered is that i get an empty response. This is my code:

```
 IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator( apikey: apikey );
 SpeechToTextService speechToText = new SpeechToTextService(authenticator);
 speechToText.SetServiceUrl(url);

 speechToText.DisableSslVerification(true);

 res = speechToText.Recognize(audio: memStream, inactivityTimeout: 180);

 Console.WriteLine("Response: ", res.Response);
 Console.WriteLine("Result: ", res.Result);
 Console.WriteLine("Status: ", res.StatusCode);
```

On the website I see that I consume my free usage. I'm 99% sure my audio file works.
I've already tried to get the result directly from the method.

```
res.result = speechToText.Recognize(audio: memStream, inactivityTimeout: 180).Result;
```

If I do that, I'll get a NullReferenceException.

It would be awesome if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Either your audio stream is empty, or you are getting errors or warnings that you need to catch. As per the API Documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=dotnet-standard#error-handling

```cs
try
{
    // Invoke a method
}
catch(ServiceResponseException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
}
```

If an exception is not being thrown, then check `res` for `Warnings`.